# How to load a log file once and then append new logs in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, c3.js

I have a JavaScript function that loads a csv file and pastes its content to a c3js graph and the function reloads every 10 seconds for real time data, it looks something like this:

```
function parseData(createGraph) {
    Papa.parse("../csv_files/traffic.csv", {
        download: true,
        complete: function(results) {
            createGraph(results.data);
        }
    });
}
function createGraph(data) {
    var Arrx = ['x'];
    var Arry = ['Frequency'];
    var dates = []; 
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length-1; i++) {
        if(moment(data[i][0], "DD-MM-YYYY", true).isValid()){
            dates.push(data[i][0]);
        }
    }
    var result = foo(dates);        
    for (var i = 0; i < result[0].length; i++){
        Arrx.push(result[0][i]);
        Arry.push(result[1][i]);
    }   
    var chart = c3.generate({
        size: {
            width: 1050
        },
        data: {
            x: 'x',
            xFormat: '%d-%m-%Y',
            columns: [Arrx,Arry]
        },
        axis: {
            x: {
                label: 'Date',
                type: 'timeseries',
                tick: {
                    format: '%d-%m-%Y'
                }
            },
            y: {
                label: 'Frequency'
            }
        },
        bindto: '#chart'
    });
}
```

The problem is that I have to load the file at every reload and it's starting to take more and more time as the file gets bigger, is there a way in JavaScript to only load it once in the beginning and then append new logs to the graph in real-time?

Answer (score 0):

While page is initialized, check the local/session storage if the csv data is available. If unavailable then load/save the csv data to the local/session storage and proceed next step.

If you need to overwrite the localstorage check, then pass a query param to url. I guess this will work for you.

Here is a guide to [localstorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)